# How to split team by intervals and assign group Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I Have a list of 82 participant in Sheet1. I want to create the group 15 members per group and assign the group name Copied from Sheet2 as Group1, Group2 and copy it to the sheet3

I am looping through total count and devided by the group size. but not finding a way on how to create the if logic and assign the group name.

I have used this code. but not getting a way to use it to assign the group name.

By using this, this code creating 15 group like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8s7h.jpg)

Need yours expertise help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example script that will divide your names into groups of 15.  Note in your question the number of intervals is 82/15 not 15.

**Code.gs**

```
function assignGroup() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let names = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let groups = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
    let groupSize = 15
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    let k = 0;
    let results = [["Group","Name"]];
    while( i < names.length ) {
      results.push([groups[j][0],names[i][0]])
      i++;
      k++;
      if( k === groupSize ) {
        k = 0;
        j++;
      }
    }
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet3")
    sheet.getRange(1,1,results.length,2).setValues(results);
  } 
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much it is working perfectly. 
I need additional improvement.
1. along with the name. is that possible to copy +5 col as well( region, gender, email, add, ID, etc.)
2. I want to group them based on the region. lets assume Sheet2 has 04 region & respective group name. how to pick groupname according to region

Basically, I have a list of users with details, 
Step1: filter the user by region, Sheet1
Step2: Split them into 15 members/group
Step3: Assign group Name defined under region(Sheet2!A:D), remove the used group name
Step4: copy the ready list to Sheet3.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are asking for too many things that I don't understand.   For example, let say there are 20 in a region.  Does that mean 15 go to one group and 5 go to the next?  Then the 5 are combiined with the next 10.  Can you see how people in regions will be scattered among groups?

Comment: I have created the example file for you. pl review 
Sheet1 - users list with region name
Sheet2 - group name under the region
Sheet3- Example data of final required output
[File link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ciriCB291Iku4mmyvLbNhLJ9lC00G9pVybwgguXL4D0/copy)